# Populate selectizeInput on first load

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Below is some code for a very simple shiny dashboard.  On tab 1 "Select" I have a radio button selector and on tab 2 "Food" I have a selectizeInput.

When the dashboard initially loads the first tab is loaded and "Fruits" is selected by default.  When I move to tab 2 however, nothing displays in the selectizeInput drop down menu dispite having an observe event linked to the radio buttons.

If I then go back to the Select tab and click on Meats, the selectizeInput populates.  If I then select Fruits again on the Select tab, the selectizeInput populates with a list of fruits.

How do I make the selectizeInput populate on first load with the list of fruits?

Thanks

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(data.table)

menu <- data.table(numb = c(rep(1,4), rep(2,4)),
               item = c("Apple", "Orange", "Grape", "Lemon", "Steak", "Chicken", "Pork", "Venison"))


ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "blue",
                    dashboardHeader(),
                    dashboardSidebar(
                      sidebarMenu(id = "initalTab",
                                  sidebarMenuOutput("menuSidebar"))
                      ),
                    dashboardBody(
                        tabItems(
                          tabItem("select",
                                  uiOutput("selectType")),
                          tabItem("food",
                                  uiOutput("selectFood"))
                          )
                    )
)

server <- (function(input, output, session) {

  output$menuSidebar <- renderMenu({
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Select", tabName = "select", icon = icon("home")),
      menuItem("Food", tabName = "food", icon = icon("sort"))
    )
  })

  isolate({updateTabItems(session, "initalTab", "select")})

  output$selectType <- renderUI({
    fluidRow(
      box(width = 3, status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
          radioButtons("foodFilter", label = h4("Filter by Food Type"),
                       choices = c("Fruits" = 1, "Meats" = 2),
                       selected = 1,
                       inline = TRUE)
      )
    )
  })

  output$selectFood <- renderUI({
    fluidRow(
      box(width = 6, status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
      h4("Select Your Food"),
      selectizeInput("group",
                     choices = NULL,
                     width ="100%",
                     NULL,
                     NULL,
                     multiple = TRUE,
                     options = list(plugins = list("drag_drop", "remove_button"),
                                    placeholder = "Please select you food"))
      )
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$foodFilter, {
    updateSelectizeInput(session,
                     "group",
                     choices = menu[numb == input$foodFilter,`item`],
                     selected = menu[numb == input$foodFilter,`item`][1],
                     server = TRUE)
  })
})


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Its not going to load like this as the output hasnt been rendered yet. you need to physically go to the next tab in order for things to load. Then and only then you can apply the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building up on my comment try adding this line `outputOptions(output, "selectFood", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)`

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(data.table)
library(shiny)

menu <- data.table(numb = c(rep(1,4), rep(2,4)),
                   item = c("Apple", "Orange", "Grape", "Lemon", "Steak", "Chicken", "Pork", "Venison"))


ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "blue",
                    dashboardHeader(),
                    dashboardSidebar(
                      sidebarMenu(id = "initalTab",
                                  sidebarMenuOutput("menuSidebar"))
                    ),
                    dashboardBody(
                      tabItems(
                        tabItem("select",
                                uiOutput("selectType")),
                        tabItem("food",
                                uiOutput("selectFood"))
                      )
                    )
)

server <- (function(input, output, session) {

  output$menuSidebar <- renderMenu({
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Select", tabName = "select", icon = icon("home")),
      menuItem("Food", tabName = "food", icon = icon("sort"))
    )
  })

  isolate({updateTabItems(session, "initalTab", "select")})

  output$selectType <- renderUI({
    fluidRow(
      box(width = 3, status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
          radioButtons("foodFilter", label = h4("Filter by Food Type"),
                       choices = c("Fruits" = 1, "Meats" = 2),
                       selected = 1,
                       inline = TRUE)
      )
    )
  })

  output$selectFood <- renderUI({
    fluidRow(
      box(width = 6, status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
          h4("Select Your Food"),
          selectizeInput("group",
                         choices = NULL,
                         width ="100%",
                         NULL,
                         NULL,
                         multiple = TRUE,
                         options = list(plugins = list("drag_drop", "remove_button"),
                                        placeholder = "Please select you food"))
      )
    )
  })

  outputOptions(output, "selectFood", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)  

  observeEvent(input$foodFilter,{
    updateSelectizeInput(session,
                         "group",
                         choices = menu[numb == input$foodFilter,`item`],
                         selected = menu[numb == input$foodFilter,`item`][1],
                         server = TRUE)
  })
})


shinyApp(ui, server)
```